# Stored procedures in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

In my use case,  I am trying to migrate SQL based traditional data warehousing application into big data infrastructure. I chose Hive and i think it is doing well. However, what I could not find is that stored procedures. Is it available in hive? I am using apache Hue to write and execute Hive query.

Comment: SP are not sported.. more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079489/why-hive-is-not-supporting-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

No, Stored Procedures are not yet available. However, there are plans to be available in the [future](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/HIVE-3087).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [HPL/SQL](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/88404/adding-and-using-hplsql-and-hivemall-with-hive-mac.html), I am looking for same solution but not try yet.